# Combine two sunspot searches with OR condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

How can I combine two sunspot search conditions with OR condition?
I tried here ↓ but didn't have success.

```
first_search_conditions = Proc.new do |s|
  s.with(:store_id, 1)
end

second_search_conditions = Proc.new do |s|
  s.with(:store_id, 2)
  s.fulltext('hello') do |ft|
    ft.fields(name_words: 90)
  end
end

def search(first_block, second_block)
  Sunspot.new_search(Offer) do |s|
    s.any_of do |scope|
      first_block.call(scope)
      second_block.call(scope)
    end
  end
end

search(first_search_conditions, second_search_conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about sunspot, but if you have two procs `first_search_conditions` and `second_search_conditions`, and want the disjunction of them, you can just construct:

```
Proc.new do |s|
  first_search_conditions.call(s) ||
  second_search_conditions.call(s)
end
```

Comment: Sunspot must combine Solr queries inside.